# Pagination of the results is not working as expected

Tags: laravel

I am using paginate() inside the controller and passing the results to view. 
I have 10 results.

If I pass paginate(3 or some number higher) dd() function is giving me

```
html "" empty string
```

If I pass paginate(2) I have some results

When I pass those results to the view I have an error

```
::name {{$name->links()}} is not recognized
```

I am puzzled here. Have no idea what to do

My paginate is working normally on my previous view.

My controller

```
public function tagnews($team_id) {

        $teamNews = Team::with('news')->find($team_id)->paginate(5);  
        return view ('news.tag_news', compact('teamNews'));
    }
```

in the view file I have

```
{{ $teamNews->links() }}
```

Models are connected with pivot table
They have BelongsToMany relationship   Team and News

Without the pagination everything works as expected. 
When I include pagination I have all these mentioned problems

Comment: find() will retrieve just one record (or null), you can not paginate it. Try removing `->find($team_id)`

Comment: Yes thanks. 
I need that find.
But I added $teamNews->news()->paginate() and now it is working fine

Comment: There is no point in eager-loading with ```with()``` if you are calling the relation function again. Use ```$teamNews->news->paginate(5)```.